# how to make the toolbar option drop down menu item to have left side custom check mark

Tags: android, optionmenu, checkmark

In the toolbar's dropdown option menu, does anyone know how to add left side check mark in the menu item?
It is similar behavior as to use <group>, but the <group> gives a default radio button in the right side of the menu item. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setGroupCheckable()` 

EDIT-1: 
use the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="all">
        <item android:id="@+id/red"
              android:title="@string/red" />
        <item android:id="@+id/blue"
              android:title="@string/blue" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

The checkableBehavior="all" converts it into checkboxes.
Edit-2:
I had posted the following code somewhere.. Refer to get started on how to customize action bar menu items :

in your style file, place the following:

```
    <style name="MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle</item> 
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/action_bar_red</item> </style> 

    <style name="MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title"> <item name="android:textColor">#F0F</item> <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item> 
    <item name="android:textSize">24dip</item> </style> 
<style name="MyActionBar.MenuTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Menu"> <item name="android:textColor">#F0F</item> <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item> 
    <item name="android:textSize">24dip</item>
    </style>
```

You can make changes in the above style items to suit your requirements. I have not added separate styling for color though. As you might observe, I am just assigning red color (which I have declared in my colors file) to it. You may change as required.

Comment: thanks for the response. but I'm looking for similar as "group" behavior but has the check mark on left side of the menu item. And it is with custom check mar icon.

Comment: For that you might have to define custom "styles" under the style tag for your application in the style.xml file

Comment: Sorry.. Forgot that I had promised to format my second edit.. I have updated that now.. Anyways, did you get a solution for the problem?